# Why is the scroll bar appearing on every page?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I get a scrollbar for the body on every page and it scrolls maybe 2em in height. This is happening on every browser IE, Chrome, Opera, and FF even in full screen (1680x1050).

I can't simply do overflow:hidden for the body because of the third test page uses SlimBox2 might needs to scroll down.

Three test pages:
http://dev.mykeepsakephotography.com
http://dev.mykeepsakephotography.com/gallery_couples.php
http://dev.mykeepsakephotography.com/invitations_weddings.php

```
body
{
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

#wrapper
{
   height: 725px;
   width: 950px;
   background: #000;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding:0;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid red; /* added for border definition */
}
```

Thank you,
LF4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `li.dir`'s within your nav are causing the scrolling. Removing them eliminates the issue. 
Within them, the `ul.dropdown ul` has an attribute

```
 top:100%
```

which is causing the issue. The nested menus here are causing elements to appear below the bottom of the page. Fix this and your problems are history :)

Throw a `position:relative;` on your `ul.dropdown > li > a, ul.dropdown li.dir {` selector and everything will work splendidly.

Position:absolute will position it absolutely to the nearest parent with position:relative, or failing that-- the document itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I just found as well.

Comment: seems like top 30px achieves the same result. Good eyes smdrager

Comment: Interesting never thought that would be the issue. Thank you I'll work on that.

Comment: Answer updated with solution-- just add position:relative to the parent.

Comment: Interesting I'm not sure which is more standard but I changed top:100% to be top:34px as the menu is 35px in height. That seemed to do the trick. I still am trying to to wrap my head around the position attribute even after reading w3schools documentation. Learning as I go. :)

Answer (score 0):

The slimbox.css has the following settings:

```
#lbOverlay {
background-color:#000000;
cursor:pointer;
height:100%;
left:0;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:9999;
}
```

I winder if height should be 725px, the same as #wrapper.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked for you by firebugging the css. That doesn't appear to fix it.

Comment: I've removed the slimbox.css and js from a page to see and the issue still was coming up so I don't think that is it. Thanks though.